Why do the Chicago White Sox wear black socks instead of white ones?
Why do the Chicago White Sox wear black socks instead of white ones?
Why are white socks not part of their uniform, since it is their name?

The team name has nothing to do with the uniform. The name refers to the historical one IIRC, but that does not necessarily mean that the modern uniform must follow that particular name.

Historical uniforms may have given the name to the team, but the uniforms on the field don't have to reflect it.   The uniform is just whatever the current team owners want to use.   Having a colored stocking (even if its not visible given most players pants length) seems to be preferred these days.
Some teams in the past have worn white socks, but lots of other things as well.   There were a few years in the 1970s when the primary color of the team was red, and they wore red socks.  But they didn't have to change the name of the team to wear them.

One possible Solution is that white socks are very hard to clean from the sand in the infield and the runners lanes. So in times when equipment was expensive to athletes and teams they relied on black socks that match the color scheme of the uniform but are not prone to stains from the infield and runners lanes sand.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
